# Node js always Getting error 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, request, header, authorization, fetch-api

I'm trying to make *POST* request on *node.js* to url, but always get **ERROR 401** (Unauthorized).

```
const response = await fetch('url', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization": 'Basic ' + Buffer.from('username' + ":" + "password", 'base64').toString('base64')
  },
  body: ''
});
```

I'm tried to use *btoa*, however *node.js* does not support that...

```
headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let loginData = "username" + ":" + "password";
let encodedData = new Buffer(loginData);
let base64data = encodedData.toString('base64');
```